# What is the name of the sql table that relates to all of the field tables

Tags: database

What is the name of the MySQL table that relates to all of the field tables

Comment: What gave you idea there is a table like that, that it's so simple? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"field_config"  contains general information/definitions.

"field_config_instance"  tells us which fields belong to which content type

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question literally, there isn't a single MySQL table that relates to all of the field tables.

There are:

- `field_config` - Holds config information for all fields.
- `field_config_instance` - Holds config information for all instances of fields.
- `field_data_*` - Holds data for multiple instances of the same field.
- `field_revision_*` - Holds revision data for the equivalent `field_data_*` table.